# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Ethereum has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Ismael]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5589014254977024).

Answer (score 9):

Congratulation @ismael.

Looking forward to collaborating with you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm also looking forward to it.

Comment: Awesome, and congratulations Ismael :) You'll do great

Comment: @Ismael As a first moderator intervention you could delete this answer since it is not an answer.                                             jk

Comment: Congratulations @Ismael ;)

Comment: @Undead8 you made my day hhh

Comment: Congrats @Ismael :)

Comment: Thank you all! @Undead8 Perhaps I should remove the whole thing since it is not a question :P

Comment: Congratulations @Ismael! :)

Comment: Congratulations!! @Ismael :-)

Comment: Congratulations!, @Ismael

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations!, @Ismael

Can you tune down the Community bot so that we would have fewer old questions popping up on the front page? A lot of them are irrelevant nowadays.

Comment: The community bot isn't something that mods can control. The bot bumps content that is answered but the answers have a score of zero. The best way to get these to stop being bumped is to vote on the answers - either up or down. Having tons of questions that qualify for the bot is usually a signal that there's not enough voting on the site. :)

Comment: Would it be possible to have some sort of notice on the Community but bumped question "This question was bumped up because no voting activity", because it is not immediately clear from the context why this is happening.